# ruby incompatible encodings when moving files

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding

I'm (unfortunately) trying to move/rename a file with UTF-8 chars in it's name. For some reason when I try to move it, I get this error:

```
ERROR Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

I've added `begin..rescue` block to see the exception thrown, and I get that no file of such name exists (it does exists, I've checked). Currently the strings are encoded in UTF-8. I'm running windows, and I'm not using Rails. Here are the bytes of the filename (`E:/Filmy/Avengers 2 - VÄ›k Ultrona (2015) cz dabing, akÄŤnĂ­, scifi BRRip.avi`):

```
[69, 58, 47, 70, 105, 108, 109, 121, 47, 65, 118, 101, 110, 103, 101, 114, 115, 32, 50, 32, 45, 32, 86, 195, 132, 226, 128, 186, 107, 32, 85, 108, 116, 114, 111, 110, 97, 32, 40, 50, 48, 49, 53, 41, 32, 99, 122, 32, 100, 97, 98, 105, 110, 103, 44, 32, 97, 107, 195, 132, 197, 164, 110, 196, 130, 194, 173, 44, 32, 115, 99, 105, 102, 105, 32, 66, 82, 82, 105, 112, 46, 97, 118, 105]
```

To move the file I'm just using the simple:

```
File.rename(from, to)
```

What encoding should I use? Any other ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a filename example? Can you show the result of `filename.bytes`?

Comment: You should give a bit more context to this question, like example code where you're doing your move.